# Sharing USB dongle internet over wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, usb-modem

I know that there are multiple guides and questions to share internet by using the hotspot however, what I'm looking is something different. I have usb router connected to computer which is connected to wifi router via a wifi adapter. Now I want to share internet so that other devices connected to wifi router can connect to internet.

Here is simplified diagram.

USB dongle (3G / 4G) <--> PC <---> Wifi router <---> Other devices

Is it possible ?

Comment: Why not turn the computer itself into a hotspot ?

Comment: @AkshBriZmohun My wifi adapter doesn't support Master / AP mode.

Comment: You have to setup your computer as a NAT router for the local network. In principle it is possible to set this up via Ubuntu's NetworkManager using the GUI. But I don't think this is viable here, because your Wifi router provides the IP addresses in the local network via DHCP. You can still configure it manually, but it requires configuring `iptables` from the command line. There are several tutorials demonstrating this, e.g http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html . You will need to adapt the interfaces.

Comment: If you attach the output of `ifconfig` to your question, I could try to write something up.

Comment: @nephente Thank you for the comment. Let me have a look at that tutorial. I will attach ifconfig very soon as I'm afk from machine.